# Linux терминал: сложности с вводом пароля

Tags: linux

Добрый день. В терминале Linux набираю команду

```
$ sudo dnf update
```

пишет

```
[sudo] пароль для vladik:
```

я ввожу пароль (правильный)

пишет

```
Попробуйте ещё раз
```

так до бесконечности
ввожу пароль учетной записи Vladik

Что за ерунда...

Comment: Очевидно, он неправильный.

Comment: CapsLock? Раскладка? Чудес не бывает - вы набираете неправильный пароль и мы вам в этом вопросе вряд ли сможем помочь.

Comment: пароль правельный капслок не включен. оказывается что
Ошибка: This command has to be run under the root user.

Comment: А вы точно есть в sudousers списке?

Answer (score 2):

Напишите пароль в текстовом редакторе, проверьте его правильность и попробуйте еще раз. Смена языка в большинстве Linux-систем - `Пуск`+ `Пробел`, регистра - `Caps Lock`.
При этом не забывайте, что при вводе пароля на терминал ничего не высвечивается (не видны символы), но ввод считывается.